How to Build a High-Performance Async Dictionary with Real-Time Update Tracking in .NET 8?
I need to implement a relatively simple dictionary class in C# with an asynchronous WaitForUpdate method. This method should allow awaiting an update to a specified key’s value asynchronously. By default, an update occurs when a new reference is passed for reference types (TValue), or a new value is assigned for value types. Additionally, the method should monitor changes within collections if they implement the IObservableCollection interface.
If a value is added or updated, the WaitForUpdate method should return immediately. What suggestions do you have for improving and optimizing this class, given that it will be heavily used in the project?
Ideally, I’d like to avoid using CollectionChangedHandlerController and creating a separate dictionary to manage it. However, I’m unsure how to control event handlers effectively without it (for example, to prevent handlers from triggering for removed or replaced collections). Any guidance would be appreciated!

Doing a quick look I have some suggestions that could be reused around the code since you are using .NET 8
CollectionChangedHandlerController class
I saw that you have a null check on EventHandler:
if (EventHandler != null)
throw new InvalidOperationException("A handler is already registered for this collection change event");

That means that EventHandler is nullable, so you can add the nullable on property:
private Event<Handler>CollectionChangedEventArgs>? EventHandler;

Optional changes:

Using Primary constructor on classes that only have one constructor


    private class CollectionChangedHandlerController(IObservableCollection collection)
{

    public IObservableCollection Collection { get; } = collection;
}



Adapt your if null exceptions:
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(eventHandler);

